# Simple Arithmetic Puzzle 1. Or is it?

Tags: mathematics

Here's a simple maths puzzle I've made up:

> $$1+0=1\\11+5=6\\5+2=3\\51+7=10\\56+13=\,?$$

Can you find the value of the question mark?

**Hints:**

> **Hint 1:** Starred questions are tremendous.

> **Hint 2:** The value of the question mark has four factors.

> **Hint 3:** Pythagoras.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $15$

Reasoning

> ans $ = \sqrt{a+b^2}$ where first term is $a$ and second term is $b$
>  so $56+13^2 = 225$ and its root is equal to $15$.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I really like this answer! It fits so well, I bet it's right.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> $-6$

Reasoning

> In each equation the replacement rule is 
>  $a + b = gpf(a) - gpf(b)$ 
>  where $gpf$ is the [Greatest Prime Factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html) function and we use the convention 
>  $gpf(0) = 0 \,\,,\,\, gpf(1) = 1$ 
>  So, $56 + 13 = gpf(56) - gpf(13) = 7-13 = -6$

Comment: Similarly, if $a + b = c$ in the OP's puzzle, then $\text{gpf}(a) = b + c$.

Comment: Good try! However it is not the one I thought of. Note that the Greatest Prime Factor function is only defined for integers greater than $1$ so the first equation $1+0=1$ wouldn't apply.

Comment: a/gpf(a) + b? So for first three that leaves just 1 on the left, then 51/17 + 7 = 3 + 7 = 10...

Comment: @WillCrawford You should post this as an answer. Though valid (if you include $1$ in the definition of the GPF), there is an answer that relies only on the most basic mathematical operations.

Comment: @WillCrawford Try to link your ideas with Hint 1 :)

Answer (score 2):

All the numbers $1, 6, 3, 10$ are the triangular numbers but just rearranged. We can make a pattern like so to generate these numbers:

> $$0 + 1 = 1\tag*{$T_1$}$$ $$0 + 1 + 2 = 3\tag*{$T_2$}$$ $$0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6\tag*{$T_3$}$$ $$0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10\tag*{$T_4$}$$

By this reason, I believe that

> the next number is also a triangular number.

Now the sequence $1, 6, 3, 10$ is ordered as $T_1, T_3, T_2, T_4$ which has the pattern

> $T_{(n)}, T_{(n+2)}, T_{(n)+1}, T_{(n+2)+1}$ for $n = 1$.

Therefore, the next answer is

> $T_{(n)+2}$ which when $n = 1$, we have that $T_{(n)+2} = T_{1+2} = T_3 = 6$ which has exactly four factors, namely $1$, $2$, $3$ and $6$.

If this pattern continued, the next triangular number would be $T_{(n+2)+2} = 21$, however my reasoning does not explain why we have to add certain numbers to form this pattern.

Comment: Good attempt. The actual formula is not based on triangular numbers, but somehow all the answers are though!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I did not understand the first hint, hahah.

Comment: What are the first letters/syllables of each word in Hint 1?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire **S, Q, A, T** and **Star, Ques, Are, Tre**. I still don't get it. I'm not wise enough.

Comment: "are= R. Combining gives SQRT. See @Abhinavsharma's answer.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire SQRT for **square root**. Good God, you are a genius! I guess I should have looked at Hint 3: *Pythagoras*. That one is the easiest because $a^2 + b^2 = c^2\Leftrightarrow c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and now let $c =\,?$ and the rest is clear.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire please continue making more puzzles like this. Seriously, hahah :D

Comment: I will :) ${}{}$